# CSS - Quando clicar mudar outro elemento

Tags: html, css

#### Eu queria saber como fazer para que quando eu clique no botão o h1 mude para a cor vermelha, apenas com css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  button:active + h1 {
   color: red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>OI</h1>
 <button>X</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando o **Checkbox Hack**:

```css
/* Checkbox Hack */
#toggle-1 {
   display:none;
}

label { 
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
  -moz-appearance: button; 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* CSS quando o checkbox está marcado */
#toggle-1:checked ~ #cabecalho {
   color:Red;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1">
  Clique aqui
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<h1 id="cabecalho">Texto</h1>
```

Comment: Show! muito bom. Obrigado pelo sua ajuda.